# incorrect right to left directtion when Arabic text with embedded variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, character-encoding

Dears,

I want to send SMS to customers includes Arabic text,Request_id between the first quotes from right, and the survey link between the second quotes from right

```
string Survey_link ="www.google.com";
string CaseID="12333";

 mySMSService(Mobile, "  "+Survey_link+" عميلنا العزيز: تم إستلام طلبكم برقم "++" وسوف يتم اتخاذ الإجراءات اللازمة بشأنه برجاء تعئبة الأستبيان التالي");
```

the message should be sent in this order from right to left

But, when l include the variables within the text l am getting below text:

```
 mySMSService(Mobile, "  "+Survey_Link+" عميلنا العزيز: تم إستلام طلبكم برقم "+CaseID+" وسوف يتم اتخاذ الإجراءات اللازمة بشأنه برجاء تعئبة الأستبيان التالي");
```

Comment: Since probably only a tiny proportion of us can read arabic, you need to be _a lot_ more verbose about the problem.

Comment: Did you copy and paste this line of code to your IDE?

Comment: Yes , I did copy it

Comment: Then I suggest you to type it or copy each string separately.

Comment: Same issue still